# GUI shader that draws different textures on corners, edges, and center?

Tags: opengl, glsl, gui

I'm working in GLSL but feel free to write a solution using any shader language, or even pseudocode / language agnostic, I can translate it myself.

I'm trying to create a shader that can draw a "window". A window is a shape that looks like this:

[image: window example, red corners, blue edges, and green center]

The corners (red), edges (blue), and center (green) contain different textures that will be rendered instead of the colors.

Currently I accomplish this by drawing the textures one-by-one in with the correct positions and sizes, but I would like to write a shader to accomplish this instead.

My initial shader is very primitive, I simply have nested if-else statements that check if the texture coordinate is in the top left, top right, top middle, etc. and select the correct texture from that, then I re-map the texture coordinate and draw the texture. I do not like this solution, because I dislike if-else statements in shaders (especially 12 of them!). Which leads to my question:

Given the window's width `windowWidth` and height `windowHeight` (in units), corner size `cornerSize` (in units), three textures `corners`, `edges`, and `fill` how can I write a shader to correctly pick which texture to draw at coordinates `texCoords`? Can this be accomplished by some clever `mix`-ing?

Some assumptions you can make:

1. Corners are always square and are all of the same size, call it `cornerSize`.
2. The left edge is always the same size as the right edge. Their widths are equal to `cornerSize` and their heights are equal to `windowHeight - cornerSize * 2`.
3. The top edge is always the same size as the bottom edge. Their heights are equal to `cornerSize` and their widths are equal to `windowWidth - cornerSize * 2`.
4. All corners use the same texture.
5. All edges use the same texture.
6. If it matters, the pixel size of the textures can be different. Sizes can be passed as uniforms if needed.

Comment: A variant of this idea which uses parts of only one texture is called [9-slice or 9-patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9-slice_scaling) and if you look for those terms you can find shader implementations, which might suit you. (I don't have one to recommend, so this is not an answer.)

Comment: @KevinReid I actually ended up implementing my own 9-patch parser and renderer yesterday, what a coincidence! :D